# Что такое "ляд"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Есть выражение "на кой ***ляд*** тебе это сдалось?"

А еще в Псковской области есть деревня *Ляды*.
Что же такое "ляд"?

Comment: Название вполне может происходить от другого слова - [Лядо (земледелие)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Лядо_(земледелие))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ляд** - "нечистый, черт", напр.: *ну тя к ляду*; замена слова *леший*. Обычно объясняют из *ледачий* "непутевый, негодный" или из польск. *lаdасzу* "черт" (из словаря Фасмера). По поводу происхождения топонима однозначно ответить трудно. Если ударение на первом слоге (ЛЯды), то вполне возможно, что название произошло от "непутевого" (ледачий). Если же ЛядЫ, то объяснение происхождения топонима может быть другим. Нужно у краеведов поинтересоваться.

Comment: Кстати, у нас в городе есть Лядской садик - может, тоже от "ляд"? Но садик сквер) хороший, в центре города. Неужели там нечистики водились :(

Comment: Вряд ли. Ляд - лядский. Лядской - от лядА. Возможно, какой-то топоним.

Comment: Да, я тоже обратила внимание на окончание. Но мало ли чего не бывает, вплоть до пьяных писцов :)

Answer (score 2):

Кажется, это одна из форм нечистой силы. То ли черт, то ли леший, скорее второе (языческий вариант нечистиков)

Comment: Вы одобряете сатанинский ник бегемотуса и его неприкрытый сатанизм? Считаете ли Вы все это невинной игрой или вообще не видите здесь никаких нарушений - пусть дяденька развлекается, как может и хочет.

Answer (score 0):

Господа-товарищи! Не знать прописные истины – плохо. В славянском языке есть противопоставление – лад и ляд, лад – это проядок, обустроенность, гармония (ладья, ладком, ладушки), а ляд – его противоположность (*лядь,). Еще в период подсечно-огневого земляделия лядом назывались брошенные поля, которые заросли кустарником и сорняками. Лядской садик – заросший, заброшенный садик. Лядово семя – так звали леших и кикимор, появляющихся в неустроенных, заброшенных местах.

Answer (score -1):

Лях - горе несчастье . от него ляд.
 Дополню. Ляхами звали поляков лихо берущих в плен ( полон ) . Сравни вор - как тать ( татарин ).
Лихо- горе. от него ляхи и далее- ляд .

Comment: Интересно, кто этому бреду плюсов наставил? Наверное, у товарища двойная регистрация! Ставлю минус!

Comment: Двойная?
Плохо же вы о груманте думаете.
Он тут порезвился на славу, всех бредунов плюсами одарил.
Хотя это только начало. Вот полюбуйтесь:

>Надо идти с «крестовым походом» на «Сеть знаний — по русскому языку». Чуть освобожусь от срочных дел и пойду. Горя они тяпнут.  

http://mathhelpplanet.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=26048&sid=7fa919fd9cc5665754b826a9484d84d5&p=139163#p139163

Comment: Согласен, версия кажется высосанной из пальца.

Comment: Комментарий бегемотуса явно тянет на месячный бан))) Чужие бредни приписывает мне, груманту/Дерзкому. Админы и модераторы, приструните КЛЕВЕТНИКА, пожалуйста, очень вас прошу! В данном вопросе нет моего ответа, нет моих комментариев, и вдруг начинают склонять мой ник?!! На кой ляд это мне нужно... Провокация бегемотуса точно рассчитана, он гроссмейстер подобных многоходовок)))

бегемотус - сатанинская кликуха, прекращаю любые с этим субъектом словопрения, пусть горит в аду(((